# What is Auth_OpenID_FileStore?

Tags: php, openid

What is the purpose of Auth_OpenID_FileStore in [php-openid](http://github.com/openid/php-openid)?

**Update**: I understood what is a FileStore. Is it safe to save the file in /tmp? Or should i move it to some other location accessible only to me? Is it better to use a database for the store?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a filesystem-based store for OpenID associations and nonces.

This store should be safe for use in concurrent systems on both windows and unix (excluding NFS filesystems). There are a couple race conditions in the system, but those failure cases have been set up in such a way that the worst-case behavior is someone having to try to log in a second time.

Most of the methods of this class are implementation details. People wishing to just use this store need only pay attention to the constructor.

http://openidenabled.com/files/php-openid/docs/2.1.1/OpenID/Auth_OpenID_FileStore.html

Comment: i couldn't understand much from that. What is being stored in the file and why?

Comment: Well its just a Way to save nonces ( number used once http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_nonce ) or an Association Between an Site and an Open ID Provider

Comment: Thanks. Is it safe to save the file in /tmp? Or should i move it to some other location accessible only to me? Is it better to use a database for the store?